# New branch/stage using Zappa

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, zappa, python-zappa

I currently have an API up on AWS Lambda using Zappa/Flask (Py 3.7)

My zappa_Settings.json file looks like so:

```
{
    "beta": {
        "app_function": "application.application",
        "profile_name": "changed",
        "project_name": "changed",
        "runtime": "python3.7",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-<obscured>"
    }

}
```

However, we are now working on a new set of features and sense dictates we have a separate branch or stage, like 'testing' where we deploy these and evaluate for maturity before pushing to the live environment.

The problem is, try as I might, I am unable to create a new stage from the console:

```
zappa init
```

crashes with

> click.exceptions.ClickException: This project already has a
>   zappa_settings.json file!

```
zappa init stage2
```

produces

> usage: zappa [-h] [-v] [--color {auto,never,always}]
>                {certify,deploy,init,package,template,invoke,manage,rollback,schedule,status,tail,undeploy,unschedule,update,shell}
>                ... zappa: error: unrecognized arguments: stage2

```
zappa deploy stage2
```

outputs

```
(botocore 1.12.86 (/home/user/Code/Python/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.82'), {'boto3'})
Calling deploy for stage stage2..
Error: Please define stage 'stage2' in your Zappa settings.
```

Now, if I manually create an entry for a stage, I need to have an s3 bucket for the deployment. Is it safe to reuse the same one from the first instance? What do I do here to deploy a new stage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zappa init` is just to get you started with the `zappa_settings.json` file, you don't need to run this each time to edit it.

for example.

```
{
    "beta": {
        "app_function": "application.application",
        "profile_name": "changed",
        "project_name": "changed",
        "runtime": "python3.7",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-<obscured>"
    },
    "stage2": {
        "app_function": "application.application",
        "profile_name": "changed",
        "project_name": "changed",
        "runtime": "python3.7",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-<obscured>"
    }
}
```

however this could be better written as.

```
{
    "common": {
        "app_function": "application.application",
        "profile_name": "changed",
        "project_name": "changed",
        "runtime": "python3.7",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-<obscured>"
    },
    "beta": {
        "extends": "common"
        // additional overrides here
    },
    "stage2": {
        "extends": "common"
        // additional overrides here
    }
}
```

Comment: That was super informative - thanks so much for answering! I've accepted your answer :)